# Syntax for memory request in a Sun Grid Engine job file

Tags: memory, gridengine, qsub

I'm submitting a Matlab job in the cluster of my university using `qsub` after having logged in a node using `ssh`.

The job runs out of memory. This is the advice I received to fix my issue: "**Possible solutions are run on a bigger machine or buy more RAM**."

What does this mean in practice for my bash file? Which lines of the bash file control the size of the machine or the RAM? At the moment, in my bash file (see below) I request `vmem` and `tmem`. Is any of these RAM?

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=18G
#$ -l tmem=18G
#$ -l h_rt=480:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 600 tasks where each task has a different $SGE_TASK_ID ranging from 1 to 600
#$ -t 1-600

#$ -N try
date
hostname


#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main_1; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; f_1; exit"
```

Comment: If the job runs out of memory, then you need to request more of it when submitting. Who gave you the advice in your question? It's unlikely that someone who is managing the cluster would have told you that.

Comment: The best option would be to talk to a local administrator or a co-worker (or fellow student) who knows more about the hardware available. They would be able to tell you how much RAM you can expect to reserve, and how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines that start with `#$` are ignored by `bash`. They are commands for the `qsub` queuing system. Any line starting with an `#` is ignored by bash, and `qsub`, specifically, uses `#$` to indicate its own arguments.

In your case, your administrator has set it up so it can take these two arguments that seem to be about memory:

```
#$ -l h_vmem=18G
#$ -l tmem=18G
```

You need to talk to the administrator of the server you are using, and ask them to tell you how you can tweak these values, or use another flag, to request more memory. The details will be specific to your setup, so we can't really help any more.